# Unit testing complex `__init__` method

Tags: python, django, refactoring

i have this piece of code which is a class `__init__` method and takes two arguments.

```
def __init__(self, port_type, request):
        self.log = Log(__name__, True)
        self.request = request
        self.sitecode = port_type.sitecode.upper()
        self.browser_default_lang = self.request.META['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'].split(',')[0]
        self.active_lang = self.request.session.get('lang', self.browser_default_lang.lower())
        self.static_folder = 'static_%s_%s' % (self.sitecode,     self.SITE_TEMPLATES_RESOURCES_SUFFIX)
        self.template_path = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, self.static_folder)
        self.template_path_port_type = '%s_%s' % (self.template_path, self.port_type.hash)
        self.site_media_path = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_URL, self.static_folder)
        self.site_port_type_media_path = '%s_%s' % (self.site_media_path, self.port_type.hash)
        self.site_config = SiteConfig.objects.get(sitecode=self.sitecode)
        self.site = UmSite.objects.get(code=self.port_type.sitecode)
        self.context = {}
```

I find it difficult to write unit tests for this. I should really write the tests first but somehow I ended up with this and have to refactor and am writing them now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a mock `request` that gives you deterministic data, without connecting to the internet. For example, make a `request` object that returns some fixed string for `request.META`, and a `session` object that returns a fixed string for `session.get(...)`, etc. Then assert that `self.active_lang` and other properties that need to be set have the right values.

Comment: Thanks. I am using 'from mock import Mock' to mock request.